# Getting the max width of every column in my table Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to loop through every column in my table and get the width of the largest cell in that column and insert that width value in array.

My table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vseci.png)

so the largest cell in first column **Name** should be **Brielle Williamson** and the largest cell in first column **Position** should be **Chief Executive Officer (CEO)** and so on...

I inset the width of these cells in an array which will look like this `var widths = ["70", "90", "60",....];`

Here is my code

```js
var max = 0; 
 var i = 0;
 var j = 0;
 var arr = [];
 
 for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) { 
 $('table tbody tr td:nth-child('+ i +')').each(function() {
    max = Math.max($(this).width(), max); });
    arr[j] = max;     
   j = j + 1;    
} 

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. It's still getting the max width in all the table not of every column. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You're getting the width of the cell, sure, but in a table cells are automatically sized to fit the largest element. So whatever cell you fetch will always be sized the same as every other cell. What width are you hoping to calculate? The width of the content?

Comment: @Rajit  if you run my code you will see this result in the alert [122,201,201,201,201,201] but for exampe column Position and Age do not have the same width

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) - what is the overall goal of finding out this data; what are you trying to do? I only ask because there might be a better way to do it than what you have in mind.

Comment: @amphetamachine I am trying the get the width of each column and insert it into array

Comment: @JuniorDev Insert it into an array, never to be read back out again? What's the point?

Comment: @amphetamachine  I want to get the width of each column so that i can customize the exported excel file with the same width as in the table

Comment: @JuniorDev I misunderstood, apologies. It sounds to me like you just want to calculate the width of each column, since the largest cell will decide the width for the whole column. You've used `Math.max` unnecessarily. You can just assign the `.width` directly to your array. Since you use `Math.max` you're finding the max width so far and assigning that same value to the array each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you use the same `max` value for all columns.

Move `var max = 0;` inside the `for` loop (or, more correctly, reset it to `0` each time, due to how js scoping works).

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var arr = [];
var max;

for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  max = 0;
  $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function() {
    max = Math.max($(this).width(), max);
  });
  arr[j] = max;
  j = j + 1;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```css
th {text-align:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

There may be ways to improve your code (eg a column will have the same width in each row, so no need to parse all the rows), but the question was about what was wrong with it and why it always gave the same value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you always keep the max value between columns here :

`max = Math.max($(this).width(), max); });`.

Hence the `201` repeating himself. As stated in the comments by Rajit, your columns automatically get set to the max width of the max cell, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Also, you have one unnecessary loop, try this instead (without the `for`) :

```
 $('table thead tr th').each(function() {
    arr[j] = $(this).width();     
    j = j + 1;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first row in `tbody` and then use `map` method to get widths of `td` elements where each `td` is one column.

```js
const columns = $("tbody tr:first td").map(function(i) {
  return $(this).width()
}).get();

console.log(columns)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in pure javascript.

```
        var trs  = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'),
            cols = 0,           // Columns length
            rows = trs.length,  // Rows length
            res  = [],          // Result
            txt  = [];          // Text values

        for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
            var row = trs[i],
                tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');

            if(res.length == 0){
                cols = tds.length;
                res  = new Array(cols);
            }

            for(var e=0; e<tds.length; e++){
                var td = tds[e];

                // Wrap text to inline element
                td.innerHTML = '<span>'+td.innerText+'</span>';

                var sp = td.querySelector('span');

                if(!res[e] || res[e] < sp.offsetWidth){
                    res[e] = sp.offsetWidth;
                    txt[e] = sp.innerText;
                }

                // Unwarp after calculating
                td.innerHTML = td.innerText;
            }
        }

        console.log(res);
        console.log(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem with your code is you should reset value of `max` variable to 0  on every iteration over new column.**

Still there is lot of areas to re-structure the code.

```js
var max = 0; 
 var i = 0;
 var j = 0;
 var arr = [];
 
 for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) { 
    max =0;//<-- Note this change
    $('table tbody tr td:nth-child('+ i +')').each(function() {
       max = Math.max($(this).width(), max); 
    });
    arr[j] = max; 
    j = j + 1;    
} 

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```